# Neural networks when gradient descent is not possible

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent

I am looking for an example in which it is simply impossible to use some sort of gradient descent to train a neural network. Is this available?

I have read quite some papers about gradient-free optimization tools, but they always use it on a network for which you can also use gradient descent. I want to have a situation in which the only option to train the network is by, for example, a genetic algorithm.

Comment: What level of example are you looking for? Creating a neural network architecture that cannot be trained using gradient descent is very easy. Describing a problem that requires finding an optimal function, where it is possible to apply a NN, but impossible to use gradients, is a lot harder. It can be the case that using gradients is not as efficient as other methods, but here you are asking for "simply impossible", which is tougher

Comment: Ideally I would like to have a neural network design that can be applied to, for example, the MNIST dataset but where gradient descent would not be possible to train the network.

Comment: OK, that's easy. Just use a non-linearity somewhere in the network which cannot be usefully differentiated. A step function in the last layer should do it (or in any other layer). It's artificial, and probably lower-performing than the equivalent network with that layer removed. But it should achieve your goals

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look into that

Comment: The basic perceptron learning algorithm (hebbian learning) cannot be optimized by GD, hopfield nets also fall in this category...just look at some old architectures when computing power was not big you'll find a lot such discrete structures.

Comment: @DuttaA This is wrong, unless by "basic perceptron learning algorithm" you mean something else. In that case, your terminolgy is at least misleading. The perceptron can and is trained using GD. See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/411216/82135.

Comment: @nbro 1.) The original inventor of perception didn't train it using GD https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/samplechapter/0/1/3/1/0131471392.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi7l6qYmvbiAhXafn0KHTCKBhoQFjAKegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3RRtOJV0dPGk_ktrVx46de 2.) Also I mentioned Hebbian Learning 3.)perceptrons are wrongly used to denote NNs IMO, the line is very thin l.

Comment: The answer you gave there is not perceptrons training algorithm, perceptrons uses Signum function on the output of final node. It might be modified perceptrons algorithm but not perceptrons training algorithm.

Comment: @DuttaA A perceptron is a neural network with one input layer and one output layer. That's what a perceptron is.

Comment: @nbro no it is not..original perceptron is not only that, there are several other constarints..you can pick any good book, they never use Perceptrons to denote NN's or anything near that like any amateur blogs, the term is heavily distorted

Comment: @DuttaA The word perceptron is often used to denote such neural network. If the original paper used a Hebbian rule to learn, it is a different story. There are actually several variants of the perceptron.